# Are there tools or plugins for IDA Pro that can find ELF sections?

Tags: ida, idapython, elf

I'm trying to use data from one ELF to build another ELF, but I can't seem to find anything that gets what I need using IDA Pro. I'm trying to build a database out of Sections, Symbols, and Cross-references. I know radare can do it, but I'm trying to get it done in IDA. I just can't seem to find many metadata exporting scripts or plugins asides from what's in IDAPython, but that doesn't seem to accomplish what I want it too.

Comment: Why are you limiting yourself to specifically IDAPython plugins? Won't third party tools work for you?

Comment: If they're straight Python or C++, then yes, but most of the other options seem to increase dependencies on various libraries, and I need to keep external dependencies to a minimum (outside of IDA).